# output not being displayed on GUI properly

Tags: java, swing, awt

I'm trying to display 4 tiles in a row. However, only the last tile seems to be displayed on the GUI and I'm not sure why. I've looked around the internet and I cant find any solution I can comprehend.
here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

// creates a GUI and displays the game tiles made in gameTile.java
public class testGameTileClass { 
    gameTile tile1;
    gameTile tile2;
    gameTile tile3;
    gameTile tile4;

    public testGameTileClass() {
        // sets up GUI
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Game Tiles");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.setSize(1280, 720);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);   
        testConstructor1(frame);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }    

    public void testConstructor1(JFrame frame) {
        tile1 = new gameTile(10, 10, 64, Color.RED.darker());
        frame.add(tile1);
        tile2 = new gameTile(84, 10, 64, Color.GREEN);
        frame.add(tile2);
        tile3 = new gameTile(148, 10, 64, Color.BLUE);
        frame.add(tile3);
        tile4 = new gameTile(212, 10, 64, Color.ORANGE);
        frame.add(tile4);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new testGameTileClass();
    }
}
```

and here is the gameTile class code:

```
    import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class gameTile extends JPanel {
    private Color color;        //color of gameTile
    private int x, y, size;     // x and y coords, and size of gameTile
    public gameTile (int x_, int y_, int size_, Color color_) {
        x = x_;
        y = y_;
        size = size_;
        color = color_;        
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillRect(x, y, size, size);
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2.drawRect(x, y, size, size);
    }
}
```

[This is my result. Is there any way to fix this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciQgM.png)

Comment: `private int x, y, ..;` AFAIU a `JPanel` already uses both of those. Use different names.

Comment: JFrame uses Borderlayout by regular, try using GridLayout or FlowLayout or GridBagLayout

Comment: I also wouldn’t use components this way

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section. Pay close attention to the [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) section.

I went ahead and created the GUI you were trying to create.

[image]

When I create a Swing application, I use the [model-view-controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) (MVC) pattern.  This pattern allows me to separate my concerns and focus on one small part of the application at a time.

I used your game tile idea and created a plain Java getter/setter class to hold a tile.  In this simple example, all I needed was the color and rectangle information.  In a more complex example, you could create a `BufferedImage` with a more detailed image than just one color.

I collected four `GameTile` instances in a separate model class.  The model class would hold all the information for the application in another separate plain Java getter/setter class.

Writing the view was straightforward after creating the model.  You have one drawing `JPanel` where you draw all the game tiles.

In this simple example, there's no controller.  The controller is made up of one or more `Action` or `ActionListener` classes.

Here's the complete runnable code.  I made all the additional classes inner classes so I could post the code as one block.  You should separate the classes into different files within a package.  For most of my Swing projects, I create separate model, view, and controller packages.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestGameTileExample implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new TestGameTileExample());
    }

    private final GameModel model;

    public TestGameTileExample() {
        this.model = new GameModel();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Game Tiles");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);

        frame.add(new DrawingPanel(model), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private final GameModel model;

        public DrawingPanel(GameModel model) {
            this.model = model;
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1200, 720));
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            for (GameTile tile : model.getTiles()) {
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                Rectangle r = tile.getTile();
                g.fillRect(r.x, r.y, r.height, r.width);
                g.setColor(tile.getColor());
                g.fillRect(r.x + 2, r.y + 2, r.height - 4, r.width - 4);
            }
        }
    }

    public class GameModel {

        private final GameTile[] tiles;

        public GameModel() {
            this.tiles = new GameTile[4];
            tiles[0] = new GameTile(10, 10, 64, 64, Color.RED.darker());
            tiles[1] = new GameTile(84, 10, 64, 64, Color.GREEN);
            tiles[2] = new GameTile(148, 10, 64, 64, Color.BLUE);
            tiles[3] = new GameTile(212, 10, 64, 64, Color.ORANGE);
        }

        public GameTile[] getTiles() {
            return tiles;
        }

    }

    public class GameTile {

        private final Color color;

        private final Rectangle tile;

        public GameTile(int x, int y, int width, int height, Color color) {
            this.tile = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
            this.color = color;
        }

        public Color getColor() {
            return color;
        }

        public Rectangle getTile() {
            return tile;
        }

    }

}
```